# How to count sentences printed out from text file?

Tags: java, count, counter, fileinputstream, datainputstream

I currently have this class that prints out all sentences containing the word "Goal" or "goal". I was wondering is there a way I could count how many sentences are printed out? The class reads Results.txt and prints out the two sentences containing "Goal" or "goal". How do I implement a method that tallys the sentences and returns the number two.

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
              // Open the file that is the first 
              // command line parameter
              FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("src\\sentiment\\Results.txt");
              // Get the object of DataInputStream
              DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
              String strLine;

              //Read File Line By Line
              while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)    
              {
                  if(strLine.contains("goal") || strLine.contains("Goal"))
                  // Print the content on the console
                  System.out.println(strLine);
              }
              //Close the input stream
              in.close();
              }

        catch (Exception e)
        {//Catch exception if any
              System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
 }
```

Comment: What is a sentence? A single line? From `.` to `.` or `!` or `?`?

Comment: Your current setup has everything in the main method. The easiest solution would be just adding a local variable that increments every time a line contains goal or Goal within your `if` statement. If that doesn't work for you, you have to pass the entire string to recount the data which seems a little redundant.

Comment: A sentence is every new single line.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to count the matching lines, just increment a counter and print it once you're done :

```
              // Initialize the counter
              int count = 0;

              // Read File Line By Line
              while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)    
              {
                  if(strLine.contains("goal") || strLine.contains("Goal")){

                      // Print the content on the console
                      System.out.println(strLine);
                      // Increment the counter
                      count++;

                  }

              }

              // Print the total
              System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Thank you. Very much appreciated!